# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor DisplayFor Delegate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, lambda, display-templates

I'm getting this error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Here's my code (custom HTML helper, wrapping DisplayFor so i can choose a template):

```
public static string DisplayLocationTypeFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, LocationType>> expression, bool plural = false)
{
   return plural ? 
      htmlHelper.DisplayFor(expression, "LocationTypePlural").ToHtmlString() :
      htmlHelper.DisplayFor(expression).ToHtmlString();
}
```

When i use it like this, it works:

```
@Html.DisplayLocationTypeFor(model => model.LocationType)
```

Because the `model` has a property for `LocationType`.

But when i do this in *another* custom HTML helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString SearchPreferenceButtonForModel<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper)
{
   // .. other code
   foreach (var property in htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
   {
      if (property.PropertyName == "LocationType")
         htmlHelper.DisplayLocationTypeFor(model => ((LocationType)Enum.ToObject(typeof(LocationType), property.Model)), true);
   } 
}
```

It errors.

I can change my `DisplayLocationTypeFor` helper to use `htmlHelper.Display` instead, but i'm not sure how.

Any ideas?

**What i'm trying to do,** is that i have a specific way of rendering out the `LocationType` model, that i want to happen across the site. Internally, the template uses a resource file, and some other smarts based on the URL.  In other words, there is logic - which i don't wanted repeated.

This way, all my views/templates call into this template as a standard way of rendering the `LocationType`.

Comment: what are you trying to do actually? Can you tell us the context? May be there are other solutions to achieve that.

Comment: @Mohayemin - edited with reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the error message:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

It's telling you that only certain types of (very simple!) lambda expressions are permitted in a Razor template.  If you have something more complex, you need to compute the value before you try to pass it to the template.  Something like this should work:

```
if (property.PropertyName == "LocationType") {
  LocationType locationType = (LocationType) Enum.ToObject(typeof(LocationType), property.Model));
  htmlHelper.DisplayLocationTypeFor(model => locationType, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. BTW, know you prob didnt mean to - but you've come across as pretty brash. I did read the message, and i've received it several times in the past. I just didn't know how to resolve it in this particular scenario. Anyway, thanks for you help!

Comment: You're welcome--glad I could help.  Sorry, I didn't mean to be brash.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by composing a display template for `LocationType` model.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5497234/887149) is an answer that says how to achieve that. In short:

1. Create a folder `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates`.
2. Create a view named `LocationType` in the new folder you created with model type `LocationType`.
   Whenever you try a `@DisplayFor(model => model.LocationType)`, the view you created for `LocationType` will be rendered.

Comment: That's exactly what i'm doing, IN that actual helper. I'm building a bit of logic on top of that. Using your example: `htmlHelper.DisplayFor(model => ((LocationType)Enum.ToObject(typeof(LocationType), property.Model)), true)` still breaks with the same error. The error here is relating to the lambda expression passed to `DisplayFor`, it doesnt like it unless the model is strongly typed to that type.

Comment: @RPM1984: I am sorry I misinterpreted your question.